# SPARQL Query on DBpedia for tiger woods types

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to find all types to which Tiger woods belongs. I am struggling with semantic and getting errors

Comment: Tiger Woods?  Is this a real question?  Voting to close. ***edit*** - just realized that he's trying to query dbpedia, but still feels like this question needs more information (e.g. what do your various query attempts look like)?

Answer (score 1):

In RDF, that a resource `x` has a given type `t` is expressed by the triple "`x rdf:type t`."  In your case, `x` is `dbr:Tiger_Woods`, so you can use a query like this:

```sql
select ?type { dbr:Tiger_Woods rdf:type ?type }
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Ftype%20%7B%20dbr%3ATiger_Woods%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Ftype%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Of course, this presumes that someone has already declared `PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>` and `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>`

Comment: @tallted, that's true. Fortunately, the public endpoint for dbpedia pre declares those and listse namespaces that it defines that way. That's why the query results there work. You can get a list of all those namespaces from dbpedia.org/sparql.

Comment: Yes, the predefined prefix list for DBpedia's public endpoint is at [http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) ... but that list has changed and will likely continue to change over time, and may not be active on every endpoint hosting DBpedia data, so it seems better to have a more complete and generally applicable answer here. :-)